# is it possible to make an object Unpenetrable?

Tags: modeling

lets say i have a cube
and i add a cylinder in another location
now when i grab my cyl. and move where the cube is, it will go inside the cube when i put it close enough.
is it possible to block this, so it will prevent me from moving the cyl, if the cube is on the way?
like let's say i have 2 roof tile that i want to place one on the other but slented
now i have to watch carefully so i will not have one tile intersect into the other, would be nice to be able to just move it as much as possible but not penetrate the other tiles faces

Comment: Do you want the collision in an animation or just for object placement?

Comment: I've never heard of such an option

Comment: There are various Snapping options. Click the magnate button and dropdown next to it allows various options.

Comment: You can also set the roof tiles to be rigid bodies and run a simulation where they will bump into each other and settle naturally.